# Numerical underflow for a scaled error function

Tags: numerics, special-functions, machine-precision

I calculate a scaled error function defined as

```
f[x_] := Erfc[x]*Exp[x^2]
```

but it can not calculate `f[30000.]`. `f[20000.]` is not very small (`0.0000282`). I think *Mathematica* is supposed to switch to high precision instead of machine precision, but it does not. It says:

> ```
> General::unfl: Underflow occurred in computation. >>
> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>
> ```

How can I calculate `f` for large values of `x`? Even with `N[f[30000], 50]`, it does not use high precision and fails.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't switch to arbitrary precision like you seem to believe. If you enter a machine precison number like 30000. all further calculations are done in machine precision. You may want to read some of the tutorials on the bottom of [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NumericalEvaluationAndPrecision.html).

Comment: The answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161285/534 is exact. It should be the accepted answer. Can you please pick it so it moves to the top?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have an analytic formula for `f[x_] := Erfc[x]*Exp[x^2]` not using `Erfc[x]` you could do what you expect.  However it is somewhat problematic to do in this form because `Erfc[x] <  $MinNumber` for `x == 27300.`

```
$MinNumber
```

> ```
> 1.887662394852454*10^-323228468
> ```

```
N[Erfc[27280.], 20]
```

> ```
> 5.680044213569341*10^-323201264
> ```

**Edit**

A very good approximation of your function `f[x]` for values `x > 27280` you can get making use of these bounds ( see e.g. [Erfc](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html) on Mathworld) :

[image]

which hold for `x > 0`.

Here we find values of the lower and upper bounds with  relative errors for various `x`:

```
T = Table[ 
          N[#, 15]& @ {2 /(Sqrt[Pi] (x + Sqrt[2 + x^2])), 
                       2 /(Sqrt[Pi] ( x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4/Pi])), 
                       1 - ( x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4/Pi])/(x + Sqrt[2 + x^2]),
          {x, 30000 Table[10^k, {k, 0, 5}]}];

Grid[ Array[ InputField[ Dynamic[T[[#1, #2]]], FieldSize -> 13] &, {6, 3}]]
```

[image]

Therefore we propose this definition of the function `f` (namely the arithetic mean of its bounds for `x > 27280` )  :

```
f[x_]/; x >= 0 := Piecewise[ { { Erfc[x]*Exp[x^2],                      x < 27280 },

                               { 1 /( Sqrt[Pi] ( x + Sqrt[2 + x^2])) 
                               + 1 /( Sqrt[Pi] ( x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4/Pi])), x >= 27280}}
                           ]
f[x_] /; x < 0 := 2 - f[-x]
```

I.e. we use the original definition of the function `f` for `0 < x < 27280`, the approximation for `x > 27280` and for `x < 0` we use the known symmetry of the `Erfc` function, which is relevant when we'd like to calculate `f[x]` for  `x < - 27280`. 
Now we can safely use this new definition for a much larger domain :

```
{f[300], f[300.], f[30000.], f[-30000.]}
```

> ```
> {E^90000 Erfc[300], 0.0018806214974, 0.0000188063, 1.99998}
> ```

and now we can make plots of `f` around of the gluing point ( `x = 27280.`)

```
GraphicsRow[{ Plot[ f[x], {x, 2000, 55000}, 
                      Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[{27280., f[27280.]}]}, 
                      PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
              Plot[ f[x], {x, 27270, 27290}, 
                      Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[{27280., f[27280.]}]}, 
                      PlotStyle -> Thick]}]
```

[image]

Comment: But why Mathematica does not switch to arbitrary precision, then?

Comment: @こじま From the docs: $MinNumber gives the minimum positive **arbitrary-precision number** that can be represented on a particular computer system. By the way: could you perhaps choose a user name that one can easily type using a standard keyboard? It's pretty difficult to @-refer to you in this way.

Answer (score 15):

I've had to work with that kind of function (relying on cancellation of large terms) before, and the most practical workaround I could figure out to be able to evaluate the function numerically is to use its power expansion near the point of trouble (here, $+\infty$).

So, get a good look at the series expansion and find out how it works (or derive it on paper):

```
Series[f[x], {x, ∞, 50}]
```

So, that means that you can use

$$f(x) \approx \sum_{n=0}^N \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{x^{2n+1}}$$

for $x$ larger than some value $X$. All that remains is to find a couple of values $(X,N)$ suitable to your needs. Because we have a series with signs alternating and terms decrease, the error is bounded by the $(n+1)$<sup>th</sup> term. Assuming we want to choose a value of $X$ in the range [20,1000], we plot the relative error after the $N$<sup>th</sup> term as a function of $x$ in this range:

```
LogLogPlot[Table[(2 n - 1)!!/x^(2 n + 1)/f[x], {n, 5, 10}], {x, 20, 1000}]
```

[image]

So, say we want to have a relative accuracy of $10^{-30}$ (which is better than machine precision), we can for example take $X=100$ and $N=10$. This gives us the following definition for your `f` function:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Erfc[x]*Exp[x^2], x < 100}}, 
   1/Sqrt[π]*Sum[(-1/2)^n*(2 n - 1)!!/x^(2 n + 1), {n, 0, 10}]];

LogLogPlot[{f[x], Erfc[x]*Exp[x^2]}, {x, 10, 10^6}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Blue, Thick, Opacity[0.4]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good idea I also wanted to work on the same direction after the university hours! Nice job...

Comment: There is also the possibility of constructing a Padé approximant from your series. For instance, `PadeApproximant[Erfc[x] Exp[x^2], {x, Infinity, {4, 4}}]` yields an approximant with absolute relative error $< 10^{-13}$ for $x > 50$.

Answer (score 14):

For numerical evaluation, there is the rapidly-converging [continued fraction](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfc/10/01/0009/) (due to Jones and Thron):

$$\exp(x^2)\mathrm{erfc}(x)=\frac{2x}{\sqrt \pi}\cfrac{1}{2x^2+1-\cfrac{1\cdot2}{2x^2+5-\cfrac{3\cdot4}{2x^2+9-\cdots}}},\qquad x > 0$$

One can use the built-in function `ContinuedFractionK[]` with a suitable cut-off:

```
With[{x = N[30000], n = 10}, -2 x /(1 + 2 x^2 + 
      ContinuedFractionK[2 j (1 - 2 j), 1 + 4 j + 2 x^2, {j, 1, n}])/
   Sqrt[Pi]]
0.0000188063
```

or, even better, use the [Lentz-](http://dx.doi.org/10.1364/AO.15.000668)[Thompson-Barnett](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991%2886%2990046-X) algorithm for evaluating this continued fraction, avoiding unneeded evaluation effort:

```
f[z_?InexactNumberQ] := Module[{c, d, h, k, u, v, y},
   y = v = 2 z^2 + 1;
   c = y; d = 0; k = 1;
   While[True,
    u = k (k + 1); v += 4;
    c = v - u/c; d = 1/(v - u d);
    h = c*d; y *= h;
    If[Abs[h - 1] <= 10^-Precision[z], Break[]];
    k += 2];
   2 z/y/Sqrt[Pi]] /; Re[z] > 0

With[{z = N[50]}, {Exp[z^2] Erfc[z], f[z]}]
{0.01128153626532, 0.0112815}

N[f[30000], 30]
0.0000188063194411439209981315314042

Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 50}]
```

[image: plot of exp(x^2)erfc(x)]

Answer (score 10):

In the interest of showing that there's more than one way to skin a cat, I present a method suitable for large positive arguments, due to [Chiarella and Reichel](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1968-0223068-4). The method uses the approximation

$$\exp(z^2)\mathrm{erfc}(z)\approx\frac{hz}{\pi}\left(z^{-2}+2\sum_{k \geq 1}\frac{\exp(-h^2 k^2)}{z^2+h^2 k^2}\right)$$

where $h$ is a suitably chosen parameter, based on the precision needed.

```
f[z_?InexactNumberQ] := 
 Module[{prec = Precision[z], y = z^2, e, h, j, k, s, t},
   h = Pi/Sqrt[(Round[prec] + 1) Log[10]]; e = h^2;
   s = 0; j = k = 1;
   While[True,
    t = Exp[-e k]/(y + e k);
    s += t;
    If[Abs[t] <= Abs[s] 10^-prec, Break[]];
    j += 2; k += j];
   h z (1/y + 2 s)/Pi] /; TrueQ[Quiet[z > 0]]
```

Again, this works best for large positive $z$, which seems to be the arguments of interest for the OP anyway. If evaluation for small $z$ is needed, a correction term has to be added to the Chiarella-Reichel approximation; see their paper for details.

Answer (score 9):

You need to avoid the underflow or overflow inside the formula $f[x\_]$. And that can be done simply by:

$$ g[x\_] := \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\ \text{HermiteH}[-1, x].$$

Use this $g[x]$ in place of the original $f[x]$, e.g. 
$ g[30000.]\approx 0.0000188063$.

To see why, look the general form of [Hermite Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Definition):

$$ H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2} \frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n} e^{-x^2}.$$

When $n=-1$, the derivative becomes an integral, and the integral bounds happen to be the same as `Erfc` in Mathematica. Therefore,

$$ f[x] = \text{Erfc}[x] * \text{Exp}[x^2] 
= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{x}^\infty e^{-x^2} \text{d}x \ e^{x^2} = g[x] .$$

i.e. we transformed $f[x]$ to a single function $\text{HermiteH}[-1, x]$, so Mathematica can see the whole purpose and achieve the said accuracy.

Comment: `Sqrt[2/Pi] Exp[x^2/2] ParabolicCylinderD[-1, Sqrt[2] x]` also works.

Comment: @J.M. That still has the exponential factor that can overflow.

Comment: This is exact. It should be the accepted answer

Comment: @becko, yes, that no longer works since 11.3; and somewhat similar to the [Dawson integral question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182241/terrible-accuracy-of-dawsonf) you asked some time back. It's all the same root problem.