# Diagnosing the numerical stability of a function

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, stability

I have programmed a function `f[x]` that seems to be very unstable numerically. More precisely, I noticed that for certain arguments in arbitrary precision, the precision of the output is *halved* compared to the precision of the input. This is very bad.

I would like to visualize the precision of `f[x]` relative to the precision of `x`, for different values of `x`. I am thinking of a plot of `f[x]` with error bars, but I am not sure how to compute and access these error bars.

This sounds like something might have thought of before, perhaps in a package or in some Mathematica function that I don't know of. In general terms my question is about the best ways to probe the numerical stability of a function `f[x]`? And hopefully find ways of improving it.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, when feeding a function an arbitrary precision number, Mathematica will track the precision of the result, but it will not compensate (because it can't without arbitrarily increasing the precision of the input) for issues like subtractive cancellation.  So, when working with arbitrary precision numbers, it is quite likely that the precision of the output does not match the precision of the input. Here are two examples:

```
Precision[1 + 1`20*^-10]
```

> 30.

```
Precision[10 - 9.9999999999999`20]
```

> 6.

On the other hand, if you work with exact numbers, and use [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N) to approximate the result, then Mathematica will increase the precision of the input as necessary (it can do this because it knows the exact input) to derive an approximate result that has the requested precision. Another example:

```
f[x_] := Sin[10^x]
```

Feeding `f` an arbitrary precision number will return a result with far fewer digits:

```
f[10`20] //Precision
```

> 8.38469

On the other hand, feeding `f` an exact number and approximating the result:

```
N[f[10], 20] //Precision
```

> 20.

will produce a result with the expected precision. This is because internally Mathematica raises the precision of the input to account for issues like subtractive cancellation:

```
ClearSystemCache[]
TraceScan[Identity, N[f[10], 20], Sin[_Real], Print[Style[#1->#2, NumberMarks->True]]&, TraceInternal->True]
```

> Sin[1.`20.*^10]->-0.48750602508751069152779429434810604167`9.746906238757202
>
> Sin[1.`41.640722947729074*^10]->-0.4875060250875106915277942943481060416764473169227868857449`31.387629186486272
>
> -0.48750602508751069153

Notice how [`Sin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin) was fed a number with 20 digits of precision first, but the result only had only 9.7 digits of precision. Then, [`Sin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin) was fed a number with a precision of 41.6 and the result had 31 digits of precision. This was enough precision to produce an answer with the requested precision.

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation. But I think it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @becko The point is, use `N[f[exact], prec]` instead of `f[N[exact, prec]]` and you don't have to worry about loss of precision.

Comment: In my case I can't do that, because it simply is too slow. In the end I have to use `MachinePrecision`. But I hope I can code `f[x]` in such a way that this doesn't lead to catastrophic loss of precision. Reading your answer gave a clearer idea of what I wanted to do. I wrote an answer, but probably something better can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way of doing it. But I defined a function

```
relprec[f_, x_] := Module[{r = f[x]}, {r, Precision[r]/Precision[x]}]
```

to compute the fold change in precision of a function `f` at `x`.

For example,

```
LogLogPlot[{relprec[Sin, SetPrecision[x, 10]][[2]], relprec[Sin, SetPrecision[x, 100]][[2]]}, {x, 1, 10000}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.5, 1.5}}, PlotLegends -> {20, 100}]
```

produces this:

[image]

showing a clear trend of `Sin[x]` to lose precision as `x` increases if the input precision is low.