# Assigning an analytical approximation to the error function erf(x)

Tags: special-functions, approximation

Working with some iterative integral equations, I have Gaussian density functions involved therein. Integrating the Gaussian function I obtain the error function. When I take the second integration, *Mathematica* is not able to provide an analytical expression. Because apparently there is no closed-form expression for the integral of the error function.

**Question:**
    Is it possible the tell *Mathematica* to consider the error function as some given exact expression which is analytically integrable?

For example

$$\mathrm{erf}(x)=\frac{1}{(1+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4)^4}$$

for some appropriate constants $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Take a look at a closely related question [Numerical underflow for a scaled error function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/numerical-underflow-for-a-scaled-error-function). I guess therein you'll find answer to your question.

Comment: hi @Artes thank you very much for your comment. I am looking at it right now.

Comment: I mean you can find only closed-form approximations, not an analytic closed-form formula.

Comment: yes but my question is that, whenever a result comes as $erf$ can I tell mathematica to use a predefined function instead of it automatically. Can I interrupt the general understanding of mathematica from the error function?

Comment: @Artes by the way I checked the solutions over there and they are some functional approximations defined as a new function, a bit different.

Comment: My [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/numerical-underflow-for-a-scaled-error-function/3856#3856) provides a very good approximation of the `Erfc[x]` function. In fact, you ask for what can be found there or you can simply adjust those tools to your specific problem. You can read another answers for a broader perspective of the issue.

Comment: If you've read that answer you can figure out e.g. this approximation: `g[x_]:= Exp[-x^2] (1/(Sqrt[Pi] (x + Sqrt[2 + x^2])) + 1/(Sqrt[Pi] (x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4/Pi])))`. Whenever one needs this can be done `Erfc-> g`.

Comment: @Artes thanks again. So what I need more is only Erfc-> g additionally and I am done right?

Comment: And you can't adapt `Integrate[Erf[t],{t,0,x}] -> x*Erf[x] + (Exp[-x^2] - 1)/Sqrt[Pi]`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could [unprotect](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ModifyingBuiltInFunctions.html) `Erf` and redefine it as you like it.

```
Unprotect[Erf];
 (* Here you define the constants and your erf approximation *)
   a1=...; etc.
   Erf[x_] := 1/(1 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4)^4;
 (* Here you perform your calculations with the approximate value of erf *)
   myComplexCalculation = Erf[x]/2
 (* When you are done, clear your definition and reprotect Erf *)
  Clear[Erf];
 Protect[Erf];
```

This can be dangerous but, as long as you know what you are doing, it will work.

A more local workaround is to enclose your 'approximate' calculation within a `Block` that blocks the definition of `Erf`:

```
Block[ {Erf},
  (* Here you define the constants and your erf approximation *)
  a1=...; etc.
  Erf[x_] := 1/(1 + a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4)^4;

  (* Here you perform your calculations with the approximate value of erf *)
  myComplexCalculation = Erf[x]/2
]
```

Is this what you were looking for or was it the actual expression for the approximation?

As a **more general approach** to temporarily modifying built-in functions within the walls of a scoping construct, you might also want to have a look at the undocumented function `InheritedBlock`, described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686710) on Stack Overflow. It appears that it will copy all definitions associated with the symbol you want to block, so that you can change, within the block only the part you need to. Basically, while

```
Block[ {builtinFun},
    code redefining builtinFun from scratch
    and using the new builtinFun
]
```

would give you a completely clean symbol for `builtinFun` to code from scratch, using

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[ {builtinFun},
    code redefining parts of the inherited builtinFun
    and using the modified builtinFun
]
```

would give you a completely modifiable copy of `builtinFun`, so that you can modify only the parts you need to modify.

Comment: It seems like this was what I was looking for. I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 4):

Altrnate to redefining `Erf` you might define your own approximate probability distribution function and work with that , eg..

```
cvals = {a1 -> .278393, a2 -> .230389, a3 -> .000972, a4 -> .078108}

(* erf approximation from wikipedia , take for what its worth *)
approxerf[x_] := 
       Sign[x] ( 
            1 - 1/(1 + a1 Abs[x] + a2 x^2 + a3 Abs[x]^3 + a4 x^4)^4) /. cvals

approxpdf[mean_, sd_] = (512/sd) Piecewise[{
     {(  
        4 g a2 + 4 a4 g^3  + Sqrt[2] 2 a1 + 
          3 Sqrt[2] a3 (g^2)  )/((4 + 2 Sqrt[2] a1 g + 2 a2 g^2 + 
          Sqrt[2] a3 g^3 + a4 g^4)^5)  /. g -> (mean - x)/sd,
        ( mean - x)/sd >= 0},
     {(  
        4 g a2 + 4 a4 g^3  + Sqrt[2] 2 a1 + 
         3 Sqrt[2] a3 (g^2)  )/((4 + 2 Sqrt[2] a1 g + 2 a2 g^2 + 
         Sqrt[2] a3 g^3 + a4 g^4)^5)  /. g -> -((mean - x)/sd), 
        True}}] /. cvals;

mynormal[mean_, sd_] = 
     ProbabilityDistribution[
        approxpdf[mean, sd], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];

Plot[ { CDF[mynormal[2, 5], x] , 
        CDF[NormalDistribution[2, 5], x]}  , {x, -20, 20}]
```

This should be equivalent - more a matter of semantics. Do you want an approximate solution to an exact problem or an exact solution to an approximate problem.

Note this performs pretty slowly..but I assume the other approach has the same issue as that analytic expression isn't particularly nice to integrate.