# How to force Mathematica not to use Erf and DawsonF functions in its output

Tags: output-formatting, special-functions

In ODE solutions *Mathemathica* uses `Erf` and `DawsonF` functions instead of the integral expressions they represent. How can I force *Mathematica* to show the integrals in its output? For example,

```
ClearAll[A];
A[x] /. DSolve[A'[x] == E^-x^2, A[x], x] /. C[1] -> 0
```

> ```
> {1/2 Sqrt[π] Erf[x]}
> ```

But I would like to see the integral for `Erf`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example ?

Comment: Integrate[E^(-t^2), {t, 0, x}]

Comment: `Block`ing `Erf` and `DawsonF` would not work. Perhaps using `InheritedBlock` to locally modify `Integrate`'s rules that have to do with the definition of those special functions could help? Look at the second part of this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34589/assigning-an-analytical-approximation-to-the-error-function-erfx/34606#34606

Comment: I don't understand this question. Is the goal to typeset the integral? If so then you should use a typesetting language like latex: you can be guaranteed latex will never turn $\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$ into `Erf[ ]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to display `Erf` as the integral you can use exact replacement rule

```
A[x] /. DSolve[A'[x] == E^-x^2, A[x], x] /. C[1] -> 0 /. 
  Erf[x_] :> 2/Sqrt[π] HoldForm[Integrate[E^-t^2, {t, 0, x}]]
```

[image]