# I don't want Erf[x]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, customization

I would much rather have the expression remain as an integral rather than have *Mathematica* convert it into $\mathrm{erf}$. Is this possible? I always end up differentiating the $\mathrm{erf}$ expression to understand what I am looking at.

Examples:

```
Erf[x]
Sqrt[π]Erf[x] + Exp[-x^2] - Sqrt[π] Erf[x + a]
Integrate[ChebyshevT[4, x] Exp[-x^2], x]
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible code of your problem.

Comment: See if this can be of some help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34589/assigning-an-analytical-approximation-to-the-error-function-erfx/34606#34606 . You could use it as a starting point.

Comment: Try `HoldForm`.

Comment: Try `Inactivate[expr, Integrate]`.

Comment: You could use `Format` to show `Erf`'s integral def., but keep `Erf` in the internal code. (Should be more efficient to calculate with.)  E.g.: `Unprotect[Erf]; Erf /: Format[Erf[z_]] := HoldForm[2/Sqrt[Pi] Integrate[E^-K[1]^2, {K[1], 0, z}]]; Protect[Erf];`.  You might do similarly with `Erfi` and `Erfc`, although you might want to add parentheses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above,

```
expr = Inactivate[x Integrate[Exp[-t^2], {t, 0, x}], Integrate];

D[expr, x]
```

[image]

You can also convert existing `Erf`'s to `Integrate`:

```
ErfToIntegrate[e_] := e /. {
  Erf[z_] :> 2/Sqrt[π] Inactive[Integrate][Exp[-t^2], {t, 0, z}]
}

ErfToIntegrate[Sqrt[π]Erf[x] + Exp[-x^2] - Sqrt[π] Erf[x + a]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Format` or `MakeBoxes` to show the integral definition of `Erf`, but keep `Erf` in the internal code. This should be more efficient to calculate with.  One issue is the constant in front of the integral won't be combined with any coefficients of `Erf[]`.

```
Unprotect[Erf];
(*Erf/:MakeBoxes[Erf[z_],form_]=.;*) (* will undo next definition *)
Erf /: Format[Erf[z_]] := 2/Sqrt[Pi] HoldForm[Integrate[E^-K[1]^2, {K[1], 0, z}]];
Protect[Erf];

Erf[z]
Sqrt[π] Erf[x] + Exp[-x^2] - Sqrt[π] Erf[x + a]
Integrate[ChebyshevT[4, x] Exp[-x^2], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here, we'll put the fraction in front of the integral sign:

```
Unprotect[Erf];
Format[Erf[z_]] =.;
Erf /: MakeBoxes[Erf[z_], form_] := 
  RowBox[{FractionBox[2, MakeBoxes[Sqrt[Pi], form]], 
    MakeBoxes[HoldForm[Integrate[E^-K[1]^2, {K[1], 0, z}]], form]}];
Protect[Erf];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's a modification of J.M.'s method in a comment.  The advantage J.M. points out is that copied output is interpreted as `Erf[z]` as input.  The difference in the modification is that `Erf[z]` is parenthesized as in the second way above. At this moment, I prefer having the rewritten `Erf[z]` displayed this way.

```
Unprotect[Erf];
Erf /: MakeBoxes[Erf[z_], form_] := MakeBoxes[
   Interpretation[
    DisplayForm@FractionBox["2", SqrtBox["π"]]*
     HoldForm[Integrate[E^-K[1]^2, {K[1], 0, z}]], Erf[z]],
   form
   ];
Protect[Erf];
```

Comment: Maybe this can be combined with Chip's approach for versions that have `Inactive[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, but I'm not seeing a good reason one would want to.  I'd rather put `Tooltip[..., "Erf"[z]]`, or highlight the whole expression with `Style` instead of just the integral sign.  (My answer basically treats the problem as an output-formatting issue, as such that's all that comes to mind.)

Comment: You got me thinking... it might even be nicer to use `InterpretationBox[]`, so I modified your code: `Unprotect[Erf]; Erf /: MakeBoxes[Erf[z_], StandardForm | TraditionalForm] := With[{xx = ToBoxes[z]}, InterpretationBox[RowBox[{FractionBox["2", SqrtBox["\[Pi]"]], SubsuperscriptBox["\[Integral]", "0", xx], RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["\[ExponentialE]", RowBox[{"-", SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"K", "[", "1", "]"}], "2"]}]], RowBox[{"\[DifferentialD]", RowBox[{"K", "[", "1", "]"}]}]}]}], Erf[z]]];
Protect[Erf];` If you copy the output of those evaluations, you'll still see `Erf[]` in the `InputForm[]`.