# Error Function Integral (Erf)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Any idea how to solve analytically this integral

```
Integrate[(a Erf[a Sqrt[b/(a^2 + b)] c])/(a^2 + b)^(3/2), a]
```

I tried substitution u=a^2 + b, but it didn't work. I don't need numerical integration or to solve via the few terms of the Taylor expansion. This seems to be very difficult to solve, but maybe somebody has got an idea.

Comment: The answers to this question might shed some light on the issue: [Numerical underflow for a scaled error function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/numerical-underflow-for-a-scaled-error-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some integrals cannot be found in terms of a finite set of functions. I'm not an expert on what the limits of *Mathematica* are, but the following suggests to me that this integral is beyond them.

The reason comes down, by a sequence of substitutions, to the fact that this integral returns unaltered:

```
-Integrate[Erf[Sqrt[1 - w^2]], w]
(*
  -Integrate[Erf[Sqrt[1 - w^2]], w]
*)
```

*The sequence of substitutions*

```
integrand = (a Erf[a Sqrt[b/(a^2 + b)] c])/(a^2 + b)^(3/2) Dt[a];
sub = Solve[u == a Sqrt[b/(a^2 + b)], a]
(*
  {{a -> -((Sqrt[b] u)/Sqrt[b - u^2])}, {a -> (Sqrt[b] u)/Sqrt[b - u^2]}}
*)

int2 = Simplify[
  integrand /. Last@sub,
  Dt[b] == 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && u > 0]
(*
   (u Sqrt[1/(b - u^2)] Dt[u] Erf[c u])/b
*)

sub3 = Solve[w^2 == b - u^2, u]
(*
  {{u -> -Sqrt[b - w^2]}, {u -> Sqrt[b - w^2]}}
*)

int3 = Simplify[
  int2 /. Last@sub3,
  Dt[b] == 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && w > 0]
(*
  -((Dt[w] Erf[c Sqrt[b - w^2]])/b)
*)

Integrate[int3 /. Dt[w] -> 1, w]
(*
  -(Integrate[Erf[c Sqrt[b - w^2]], w]/b)
*)
```

This last integral is nearly the same as the first one.  Somehow I tend to believe that if the integral could be done, *Mathematica* would do it.