# How to find the maximum of this function on the positive real line?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, special-functions

I need to maximize this function on the positive real line:

$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)^{14}}\cdot\frac{1}{{\frac{323.6}{14x}}^{14x}}\cdot(1.22578*10^{19})^{x-1}e^{-14x}
$$
the correct answer should be around $x=514$, but I could not use mathematica to show it. My plot has a peak at $x=680$ instead. I want to ask if anyone has any idea how to get the correct answer.

The code I am using now is:

```
A = 1/Gamma[x]^{14}*(301.6/(14*x))^{-14 *x}*(1.22578*10^{19})^{x -1} E^{-14 x}
```

and I plot it by

```
Plot[A, {x, 513, 700}, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

The result is something very strange:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the code you've used?  Interestingly, using `NMaximize` I'm getting results depending on the upper bound of `x`. However with `NMaximize[{f[x], 10^3 > x > 0}, x]` I get `{1.82059*10^-9, {x -> 514.197}}` which seems correct comparing with an appropriate plot.

Comment: I used:A = 1/Gamma[x]^{14}*(301.6/(14*x))^{-14 *x}*(1.22578*10^{19})^{x - 
     1} E^{-14 x}, Plot[A, {x, 513, 700}, PlotPoints -> 1000]

Comment: What do you mean? I have answered your question with my code.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Fine. I shall correct it.

Comment: @Artes: Updated. Hopefully now it is clearer.

Comment: Given the syntax you used in the expression, e.g. `E^{-14 x}`, are you aware that `{` brackets are used for *lists* in Mathematica?  You might easily run into problems if you use this notation for something it's not meant for ...

Comment: @Szabolcs: I see. I double checked, I think it is the $1/(1618/(70 x))^(14 x)$ term that caused the problems. Thanks for his/her's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't like using approximate numbers when we can use exact ones, therefore with `Rationalize` and `RootApproximant` I can rewrite the function this way:

```
f[x_] := 1/Gamma[x]^14 1/(1618/(70 x))^(14 x) 12257800000000000000^(x - 1) Exp[-14 x]
```

let's plot this function:

```
Plot[ f[x], {x, 0, 1500}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

We can use:

```
NMaximize[{ f[x], 10^5 > x > 0}, x]
```

> ```
> {1.82059*10^-9, {x -> 514.198}}
> ```

which most likely is a good approximation. 
However when we use e.g.

```
NMaximize[{ f[x], 10^6 > x > 0}, x]
```

> ```
> {3.92756*10^-30, {x -> 0.327666}}
> ```

we get an incorret result. It may depend on the computer system one uses.
I guess this issue is explained with anwswers to this  post:
[Numerical underflow for a scaled error function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/numerical-underflow-for-a-scaled-error-function).

Answer (score 4):

Following Artes' `Rationalize`ation, why don't you simply find where the first derivative goes to zero?

```
f[x_] := 1/Gamma[x]^14 1/(1618/(70 x))^(
    14 x) 12257800000000000000^(x - 1) Exp[-14 x]

Plot[f'[x], {x, 100, 1100}]

FindRoot[f'[x] == 0, {x, 500}]

    {x -> 514.198}
```

Comment: For the record: A zero derivative is only a *necessary* condition for a *local* extremum, not a sufficient condition. And even if have a local extremum there, you still don't know from the first derivative's vanishing whether it's a local minimum or a local maximum. Of course additional information, such as a plot, can suggest (but not prove) you really have a local max and that it's a global max.

Comment: The OP already knew there was a maximum near 500. By looking at the plot of the derivative you can see what is happening. The black-box NMaximize is no different than looking to a plot (there is no proof, just the hope that it is as the software says). A detailed study of the function can be done by analyzing how first and second derivative behave, but that's math, not Mathematica...