# Calculate an integration limit to obtain a certain area under a curve

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function that looks like a sigmoid curve. I would like to calculate the right integration limit so that the area under the sigmoid curve has a given value.

my curve:

```
model = (3.70288 E^(-((0.134844 (30.8 - 17.8731 t)^2)/t)))/Sqrt[t]
```

I tried:

```
Solve[Integrate[model == 10^-2, {t, 0, x}], x]
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: By this piece of code `Solve[ Integrate[ model == 10^-2, {t, 0, x}], x]`  I guess you mean: "find x such that the area under the curve is `10^-2`". However this code cannot do that, `Integrate` works on functions, not on equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since *Mathematica* is a really powerful symbolic computing system I recommend  to proceed symbolically as far as we can.

We define a function `curve` depending on `t` and four real positive parameters `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`:

```
curve[t_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := a Exp[-((b (c - d t)^2)/t)]/Sqrt[t]
```

Now *Mathematica* can evaluate this integral symbolically:

```
integral[x0_, x_, a_, b_, c_, d_] =
  Integrate[ curve[ t, a, b, c, d], { t, x0, x}, 
             Assumptions -> Join[{ x0 <= x, x >= 0}, 
                                  Thread[# > 0 &[{a, b, c, d}]]]]
```

> ```
> -((a Sqrt[ Pi] (Erf[Sqrt[b/x] (c - d x)] - E^(4 b c d) Erf[Sqrt[b/x] (c + d x)] 
> + Erf[(b (-c + d x0))/Sqrt[b x0]] 
> + E^(4 b c d) Erf[(b (c + d x0))/Sqrt[b x0]]))/(2 Sqrt[b] d))
> ```

We have assumed the lower limit of integration `x0`, if we had assumed `x0 == 0` the system couldn't provide a symbolic result yielding only an unsatisfactory warning:

> ```
> Integrate::idiv: "Integral of E^(-((b (c-d t)^2)/t))/Sqrt[t] does not converge on {0, x}."
> ```

However our integral can be evaluated in the limit as `x0 -> 0`:

```
area[x_, a_, b_, c_, d_] =
  Limit[ integral[ x0, x, a, b, c, d], x0 -> 0, 
         Assumptions -> {x >= 0, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0}]
```

> ```
>  (a Sqrt[ Pi] (1 - E^(4 b c d) - Erf[ Sqrt[b/x] (c - d x)]
> + E^(4 b c d) Erf[ Sqrt[b/x] (c + d x)]))/(2 Sqrt[b] d)
> ```

Now you can solve your equation with `Solve` providing rational parameters (possibly using appropriate options), otherwise for real parameters use `NSolve` or `FindRoot`. Now, it is reasonable to search for numeric solutions since there are `Erf` functions involved. Your original parameters haven't been justified and it might be necessary it play with `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecissionGoal`. E.g. we can easily find the upper limit of integration `x` for these reasonable parameters:

```
FindRoot[ area[x, 0.2, 0.3, 6.1, 3.1] == 0.01, {x, 0.5}, 
          AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

> ```
> {x -> 1.26325}
> ```

In case of your parameters there appear underflow and overflow issues, for more on these topics read e.g.: [Numerical underflow for a scaled error function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/numerical-underflow-for-a-scaled-error-function)