# Trying to compute erfcx(x)?

Tags: numerics, special-functions

The function `erfcx(x) = exp(x^2)erfc(x)` is sometimes provided in numerical packages to avoid numerical underflow for large values of `x`. But Mathematica does not provide a native implementation of this function.

Any suggestions as to what can I use to compute $\exp(x^2)\mathrm{erfc}(x)$ accurately for large values of $x$?

**Edit:** I just realized this is a duplicate of [Numerical underflow for a scaled error function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/numerical-underflow-for-a-scaled-error-function), which contains very detailed answers. So I'm closing this one.

Comment: Underflow rather than Overflow?

Comment: What do you consider large values of $x$?  `N[Exp[x^2] Erfc[x] /. x -> 1000000, 500]` works fine.

Comment: you can also use `2 HermiteH[-1, x]/Sqrt[Pi]`.

Comment: @JimB - extreme precision isn't necessary. Even low arbitrary-precision works fine, e.g., `N[Exp[x^2] Erfc[x] /. x -> 1000000, 15]`

Comment: Do those numerical packages just use the approximation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi } x}$ for $x>10^6$ ?

Comment: @BobHanlon I was being extreme in an attempt to get the necessary information to answer the question.  I was recently told by a number theorist that numbers aren't large until they reach 10^100 (which is way out of my price range).

Comment: That's arbitrary precision, which works but is very slow. Try machine precision, e.g., `x = 50.0; Exp[x^2] Erfc[x]`  underflows. @BobHanlon. This shows up (for example) if you try to plot the function.

Comment: @JimB I don't know if that's the approximation used in other libraries, but I could use it.

Comment: `x = 50.0\`20; Exp[x^2] Erfc[x] // AbsoluteTiming` evaluates to `{0.00035, 0.011281536265323773}`. Doesn't seem very slow.

Comment: `LogLinearPlot[Exp[x^2] Erfc[x], {x, 1, 1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]` plots fine.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks! That's exact and works perfectly.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform If you post an answer with that I'll accept it. Just for future reference, since I foget this often and have to come back here to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the approximation $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi } x}$ when $x>5*10^6$:

```
erfcx[x_] := If[x > 5*10^7, 1/(x Sqrt[π]), Exp[x^2] Erfc[x]]
erfcx[10^50] // N
(* 5.6419*10^-51 *)
```

One potential reference is [Closed‐form approximations to the error and complementary error functions and their applications in atmospheric science](https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/asl.154).